# What does the double hash `##` in an XML element attribute mean?

Tags: xml, bpmn

I am reading the spec for BPMN 2.0 (http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/) and came across the usage of a double hash mark `##` as the first characters of the value of an XML element attribute. For example:

`<semantic:userTask implementation="##unspecified" completionQuantity="1" isForCompensation="false" startQuantity="1" name="edit  1st level ticket" id="_6-145">`

Or look at the spec pdf file table 10.9 and table 10.45 for an example. This pdf contains many more places where this syntax is used.

As I was wondering what this means, I started searching. I see it used in XML schema `any` element (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_any.asp), namespace attribute, for which the value always seems to start with `##`.

In BPMN, it seems that it is used when they (the writers of the spec) want the user to specify what technology she wishes to use as implementation. The default would be a web service, but they try to leave that up to the user. The user may use `##Unspecified`, or `##WebService`, or provide some URI instead.

I can't find anything about the double hash in XML and why it is used in this way.

Why is `##` used here? What does it mean? What is the origin? What is it called?

Edit. I accepted Michael Kays answer, but I would still be interested to hear if anyone knows if this is specified oficially somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in particular. In XML Schema tokens like "##other" are used because they are not valid URIs (a valid URI cannot contain "##") and therefore cannot be mistaken for a namespace. Perhaps BMPN is using this convention for the same reason, or perhaps it has its own reasons. Either way, it doesn't mean anything at the XML level, it's a convention used in your particular vocabulary, and they might well have chosen it simply because it stands out better than "**" or "$$".

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense: to distinguish between a URI and something that is not supposed to be a URI (machine readable). Is this convention specified or explained anywhere 'oficially' (at least, in XML context)? As for BPMN, I figure they follow conventions used in XML/XSD.

Comment: Is it explained anywhere "officially"? Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I looked again (also after learning the hash sign is also known as number sign or pound sign, I didn't know that) but I couldn't find anything too. I would be interested to hear if anyone knows of a specification.

Comment: Please don't call it a pound sign, because in the UK that means "£".

Comment: Calling it a Pound sign doesn't make sense to me either, but it is correct (and used) in American and Canedian English.

Comment: I know that. So don't use it unless you are sure all your readers are familiar with American and Canadian English, and are aware that that is the variant of English that you are using.